# Hackerrank: Max Score

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, bitwise, dynamic-programming

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/rookierank-3/challenges/max-score)

> Consider an n-element sequence of integers, A = {a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>0</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-1</sub>}. We want to perform \$n\$ operations on \$A\$, where each operation is defined by the following sequence of steps:
>
> 1. Remove any integer, a<sub>i</sub>, from \$A\$ and set it aside.
> 2. Calculate *score<sub>k</sub>* = *runningSum* mod a<sub>i</sub>, where 1 ≤ k ≤ n and *runningSum*  is the sum of all the numbers removed from A during the previous k - 1 operations.
> 3. Update *runningSum* such that *runningSum* = *runningSum* + a<sub>i</sub>, where a<sub>i</sub> is the integer that was removed from A during step 1 above.
>
> [image]
>   [image]

**Introduction of Algorithm**

The max score is the first medium level algorithm on Hackerrank Rookie 3 contest in May 5, 2017. The success rate is 14.10%, and I only scored 3.5 out of 35 points in the contest. In the contest, I did some work on recursive algorithm, but failed to implement the correct memoization, and did not know that bit mask is the solution to solve timeout issue.

After the contest I was busy to learn and teach myself. I thought that if I am a good tester, very patient to go over a few simple test cases first, I must have solved the problem.

So I like to try the idea on the algorithm after the contest. Two unit test cases are chosen, one is the array {\$1, 2\$}, and the other is {\$1,2,1\$}.

**Test case {1, 2, 1}**

C# code only passed first 5 test cases, timeout last 5 test cases. Source code can be looked up from [the link](https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/49a61a19c6a49b79d921caca7e9cc37e). The solution is implemented with the correct memoization matching the recursive tree, but timeout since too many string concatenation.

Suppose that the array has three numbers, int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 1}.

Calculated variable as Dictionary has the following:
[0 1, 0]
[0 2, 0]
[0, 1]
[1 2, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 1]
[,1]

The key is encoded using the function:

```
 public static string EncodeKey(HashSet<int> numbers)
 {            
    int[] sorted = numbers.ToArray(); 
    Array.Sort(sorted);
    return string.Join(" ", sorted); 
 }
```

Debug the code, and check how many times the dictionary is looked up. 3 times.
key = "0 1", "0 2", "1 2".

Draw a recursion tree for this simple test case. Here is the graph:
[image]

**Apply bit mask technique**

In order to solve time out issue, I had to use bit mask instead of using encoded key by using the above function **EncodeKey** with the argument **HashSet numbers**, apply bit mask techniques learned through top coder article called [A Bit of Fun: Fun with Bits](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/a-bit-of-fun-fun-with-bits/). The code is much easy to follow after I did draw recursive tree on the test case, and bit mask set operation is also easily to look up through the top coder article.

Here is C# code with those two test cases. C# code passes all test cases on Hackerrank. Please help me to be a good tester, a smart problem solver to work on basics first.

```
  #if DEBUG
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
#endif

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MaxScore_usingBitArray
{
    class MaxScore_usingBitMask
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// source code reference is here:
        /// https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/rookierank-3/challenges/max-score/forum/comments/299005
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessInput();
            //RunTestcase(); 
        }       

        public static void ProcessInput()
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var data = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            long[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(data, Int64.Parse);

            long maxScore = GetMaximumScore(numbers);
            Console.WriteLine(maxScore);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// How to calculate score? 
        /// Please read the problem statement. 
        /// For test case int[]{1,2}, if first number array 1 is selected first, score 0 % 1 = 0. 
        /// Sum will be 1, and then number 2 will be scored as 1 % 2 = 1. Total score is 0 + 1 = 1. 
        /// There are 2 options to enumerate 2 numbers, maximum score is to choose maximum one of 
        /// those two options. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static long GetMaximumScore(long[] array)
        {            
            return getMaxScore(array, 0, array.Sum());
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, long> memo = new Dictionary<int, long>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Bit mask technique to solve timeout issue - 3 seconds time limit. 
        /// use the following article on topcoder for reference: 
        /// https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/a-bit-of-fun-fun-with-bits/
        /// The following function uses an integer to represent a set, with a 1 bit representing
        /// a member that is present and a 0 bit one that is absent. 
        /// The following set operations are used in the function:
        /// Set Union  A | B
        /// Clear bit 
        /// A &= ~(1 << bit)
        /// Test bit  (A & 1 << bit) != 0
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numbers"></param>
        /// <param name="bitmask"></param>
        /// <param name="sum"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static long getMaxScore(long[] numbers, int bitmask, long sum)
        {
            if (memo.ContainsKey(bitmask))
            {
                return memo[bitmask];
            }

            var maximumScore = 0L;

            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                var bitToCheck = 1 << i; // set ith bit

                if ((bitmask & bitToCheck) != 0) // test bit
                {
                    continue;
                }

                bitmask |= bitToCheck; // set union 

                var current = numbers[i];

                var score = ((sum - current) % current) + getMaxScore(numbers, bitmask, sum - current);

                bitmask &= ~bitToCheck; // backtracking, clear the bit - ith bit 
                maximumScore = Math.Max(score, maximumScore);
            }

            memo[bitmask] = maximumScore;

            return maximumScore;
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    [TestClass]
    public class Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {                        
            var array = new long[] { 1, 2};

            MaxScore_usingBitMask.memo.Clear(); 
            long maxScore = MaxScore_usingBitMask.GetMaximumScore(array);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(maxScore == 1); 
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test2()
        {
            var array = new long[] { 1, 2, 1 };

            MaxScore_usingBitMask.memo.Clear();
            long maxScore = MaxScore_usingBitMask.GetMaximumScore(array);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(maxScore == 1);
        }  
    }

#endif
}
```